# Determining type of connection in spring social

Tags: spring, spring-social

Is there any way to find out the current connection type of logged user? I want to know if the user is logged by Facebook, Twitter or no social account.

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recently I also had to verify the connection type of a given user.

In Spring Social you can verify the connection type using getApi(). Assuming that the connection has already been created (probably through ConnectSupport#completeConnection), then you just need to add something like this:

```
if (connection.getApi() instanceof Facebook) {
  System.out.println("Facebook connection");
} else if (connection.getApi() instanceof Twitter) {
  System.out.println("Twitter connection");
}
```